# Css fit a fixed div into another div with different resolution

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone I have a div area which has position fixed. And I have another div which I call "page" and contains fixed div. But when I check my design with different resolution every others divs fit to my "page" div but  fixed position div  can't fit my page div.

Here is my div:

```
.page {
    width: 964px;
    margin-top:6px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image:url(../images2/images/orta_alan_bg_GOLGE.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

Position fixed div

```
#rocket_left
{
  width:127px;
  height:148px;
  background-image:url(../../images2/images/tapinak_resim.jpg);
  top:244px;
  left:73px;
  position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make it correct by using the margin,padding, position in % instead of fixed pixal

Comment: @learnmore try using the css3 media query so that you can apply css on specific screen resolution and then set